# Nginx + Let's encrypt Ошибка при настройке

Tags: linux, nginx, letsencrypt

Сгенерировал certbot'ом сертификаты, прописал их в конфиге nginx

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name NAME

        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;


        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8;

        root /home/rd/www/web;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Но при `nginx -t` получаю

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Однако файл(точнее симлинка) есть

Comment: `No such file or directory: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'`

Comment: Уточнил. Файл есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего симлинк создан неправильно. При его создании не проверяется существование файла. Например

```
$ ln -s foo/test.txt test.txt
```

Затем проверяем

```
$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx  1 dimka dimka   12 мая 20 15:37 test.txt -> foo/test.txt
```

Но при этом

```
$ cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Но симлинк таки есть. Проверьте свой

```
$ ls -al /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
$ cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
```

Comment: Я понял в чём дело! certbot создал папку example. **org**, а в конфиге example. **com** Когда я в этой папке -- симлинка нормальная и сертификат открывается, а вот когда открыл по абсолютному пути, то ничего не получил. Замыленный глаз не сразу увидел разницу в доменах